# jointjs display port title on hovering

Tags: jointjs

I want to display port title when user hover on port.In title I basically want to display the port name.

this is my code -
in the definiation I am adding the title attribute-

```
portMarkup: '<g class="port port<%= id %>"><circle class="port-body"/><text class="port-label"/><title class="mytitle"/></g>'
```

and on hovering on port this is the logic-

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("[magnet=true]:not(.element)").hover(function(){

console.log("yes")

var magnetelement=$(this);

var firstelement=magnetelement[0];
var portname=firstelement.getAttribute('port');


var cell;
var index;
var allelement=graph.getElements(); 

for(var j=0;j<allelement.length;j++)
{

    var cel=allelement[j];

    if(cel  instanceof joint.shapes.devs.Model)
    {
        var outportsarr=cel.get('outPorts');
        for(var i=0;i<outportsarr.length;i++)
        {
           if(portname==outportsarr[i])
           {

                index=i;
                cell=cel;

                break;
            } 
        }

    }               
}
cell.attr('title/text',b);

}});
```

hover gets triggerd for first time and display correctly the port name in title but after that I get an error in console "Error: Invalid value for  attribute transform=" ""
after this error , hover is not triggered again.

can anyone help me in this?